# How to stop error "Column username cannot be null" when I enter a value

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a c# admin system where the admin can create new user accounts. I have written the code with MySQL queries written application side but am trying to convert it into stored procedures. I am getting an error when I enter a new user account that says that `Column 'username' cannot be null`. This is happening even when there is text inside the username textbox. I have the code working perfectly fine with the SQL application side, but am having trouble getting it to work with stored procedures instead.

I believe that there is also an issue with with the code below with checking if the username exists as it says that the username is unique, even if it isnt. This may be causing the later issues.

```
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)  //This is returning false everytime I call this method
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exists");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unique");
                return false;
            }
```

This is what my code currently looks like (Sorry for the amount of code):

**Update: I have simplified this and added comments**

```
 public bool Confirm()
    {
        string user = usernameField.Text;
        string password = passwordField.Text;
        string email = emailField.Text;
        bool admin = adminCheckBox.Checked;
        if (Create(user, password, email, admin)) //Calls the Create Method with the parameters of the textboxes
        {
         //Does something if true
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
         //Does something if false
            return false;
        }
    }
    public bool Create(string user, string pass, string email, bool admin)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("AdminCreatePlayerAccount", Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", admin);
        Conn.Open();
        try
        {
            if (!checkInputFields()) //If the checkInputFields method returns false
            {
                if (!checkUsername(user)) //if the checkUsername method returns false with the parameter of the user value (usernameField.Text)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            //If true creates user
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Conn.Close(); //Close connection if false
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        Conn.Close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Conn.Close(); //Close connection if false
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Conn.Close();//Close connection if false
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Conn.Close();
            return false;
        }

    }
    public bool checkUsername(string user) //This method is to check if the database contains a row with the inputted username
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("AdminCheckUsername", Conn))
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", user);
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)  //This is returning false everytime I call this method
            {
                //Returns true if the username exists in the database
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //Returns false if the username doesn't exist in the database
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool checkInputFields() //Checks the length of the input fields
    {
        if (usernameField.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("username") ||
            passwordField.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("password") ||
            emailField.Text.ToLower().Trim().Equals("email"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All Details");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the stored procedures I have created:

```
drop procedure if exists AdminCreatePlayerAccount; 
delimiter //
create procedure AdminCreatePlayerAccount(IN `user` varchar(100), `password` varchar(100), `email` varchar(100), `admin` tinyint)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, user_password, user_email, user_loginStatus, user_loginAttempts, user_accountStatus, user_isAdmin) 
            VALUES (@user,@password,@email, 0, 0, 0,@admin);
        COMMIT;
    END//
delimiter ;                                                                                                                                      


drop procedure if exists AdminCheckUsername; 
delimiter //
create procedure AdminCheckUsername(IN `uname` varchar(100))
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
            From tbl_user 
                WHERE `username` = @uname;
        COMMIT;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

And this is what the original code looks like when I am not using stored procedures:

This works exactly how it should, but I need to convert it so that the SQL queries are server side, not application side.

```
public void Confirm()
{
    //Add a new User
    Connect database = new Connect();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_user (username, user_email, user_password, user_loginAttempts, user_accountStatus, user_isAdmin) VALUES (@uname,@email,@pwd, 0, 0,@admin)", database.getConnection());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@uname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernameField.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordField.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailField.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", adminCheckBox.Checked);
    //Open Connection
    database.openConnection();

    //Calls checkInputFields to see if the user has inputted data into all fields
    if (!checkInputFields())
    {
        //Calls checkUsername to see if the username already exists in the system
        if (checkUsername())
        {
            //If the username already exists, it opens a message box that displays "This Username Already Exists, Please Enter a new one try loggin in"
            MessageBox.Show("This Username Already Exists, Please Enter a new one", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            //Execute The Query that creates a new account
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                OpenSettings();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter all details", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    //Close Connnection
    database.closeConnection();
}//Main method
public Boolean checkUsername()
{
    Connect database = new Connect();
    String username = usernameField.Text;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From tbl_user WHERE `username` = @uname", database.getConnection());
    command.Parameters.Add("uname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(table);

    /*Check to see if username already exists*/
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        /*Login Success*/
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        /*Login Error*/
        return false;
    }
}
public Boolean checkInputFields()
{
    String username = usernameField.Text;
    String password = passwordField.Text;
    String email = passwordField.Text;

    if (username.ToLower().Trim().Equals("username") || password.ToLower().Trim().Equals("password") || email.ToLower().Trim().Equals("email"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public void OpenSettings()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Account Has Been Created Successfully", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.Hide();
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.ShowDialog();
}
}
```

Any help to fix this would be appreciated, or help with converting inline SQL queries to stored procedures.

Comment: It seems like you've posted more code than is probably needed to reproduce your issue. Please can you create a [mcve] and share that with us instead.

Comment: Its probably as simple as I can make it. I could add in comments to say what each part does if that helps

Comment: Ive edited it a bit

Comment: Which method is the exception occurring in?

Comment: I believe it is happening when I do cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() within the Create method. Which causes the Confirm method to return false

Comment: I feel like I have done something wrong when creating the checkUsername method while trying to convert the SQL to a stored procedure

Comment: In that case a [mcve] would look like [this](https://pastebin.com/26t2Yaf8) (with the stored procedure definition to support it, of course). If this doesn't reproduce the issue for you by itself, then your issue is elsewhere. You should probably pinpoint exactly where the issue is (using breakpoints, stepping through with the debugger, and examining individual variable values can help with this) and then provide a [mcve] just for that one thing.